# Can't connect to the server using websocket sampler in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance

please help , I'm connecting to the server through websocket sampler using jmeter , when I send the request to server name https://servername , this error is displayed [ - Invalid URI syntax: Expected closing bracket for IPv6 address at index 13: wss://[https://servername]:8000/?] , when I remove the https protocol , the request is not sent and not displayed in listener and the data is not updated in DB

Answer (score 1):

You should be placing any protocol into Server Name or IP field. Theoretically you can put `https://servername:8000` into "Path" input, but I it won't work as [WebSocket expects only `ws` or `wss` protocols.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket)

> The WebSocket protocol specification defines ws and wss as two new uniform resource identifier (URI) schemes[4] that are used for unencrypted and encrypted connections, respectively. Apart from the scheme name and fragment (# is not supported), the rest of the URI components are defined to use URI generic syntax.

If you don't see the request, most probably you configured WebSocket Sampler incorrectly as if you leave response and/or close connection pattern blank WebSocket Sampler will wait for the response for 20 seconds (or whatever you have define as a connection Timeout)

See [WebSocket Testing With Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/websocket-testing-apache-jmeter) article for more information and example test plan.

Answer (score 0):

I started to use a new [Websocket library](https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers) which you can install using the [plugin-manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

See example:

[image]